# How can I make Codeigniter function variables globally available?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a simple game where the user will randomly be generated a bingo board. Once they initialize the game (i.e. round 1 after clicking "start" on index.php), the code starts using a new controller (bingo_play.php). This controller tracks the tiles that have been marked and the information in each tile.

Here's the code:

```
$card['products'] = array(
    1 => 'hamburger',
    2 => 'fries',
    3 => 'soda',
    4 => 'taco',
    5 => 'bacon',
    6 => 'onions',
    // etc.
);

if ($card['card_number'] == 1)
{
    $card['card_entries'] = array(
        'a1' => '2', 
        'b1' => '8',
        'c1' => '11',
        'a2' => '9', 
        'b2' => '14',
        'c2' => '1',
        'a3' => '16', 
        'b3' => '15',
        'c3' => '23'
    );
}
```

I suppose I could assign them as session data, but didn't think that would be the best move. Not really sure as I'm brand new to Codeigniter. In just a normal PHP project, I probably would just run an `include()` to the function.

My question is, what is the best way to make the tiles' id and text available through multiple function calls without having to check and assign the array in each function?

Comment: look into dependency injection containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`global` variables and `$GLOBALS` can lead to a lot of problems, and on top of that can be extremely difficult to debug. They have their use, but once you start approaching every problem this way, things can get out of hand and difficult to maintain.

> My question is, what is the best way to make the tiles' id and text
>   available through multiple function calls without having to check and
>   assign the array in each function?

While I'm not 100% clear on what you're working with, and if the card data is static or not, or if users can have several cards or update cards, these tips might help:

If the data never changes, use the [Config class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html) to your advantage. Store it in a config file, load it, and read the items with `config_item()` or `$this->config->item()`.

If there's more to it than just some static data, consider creating a class/library to handle everything "bingo board" related. A very simple example:

```
class Bingo_Board {

    private $card;

    function get_card($id)
    {
        // Assign the values to the $card property if not set yet,
        // getting the values from the database, a file, or wherever they are
        // Randomize them, do whatever you want
        if (empty($this->card))
        {
            $this->card = array(/* your data here*/);
        }

        // Return the card
        return $this->card;
    }
}
```

Then you can access the card like so:

```
$this->bingo_board->get_card();
```

The values will be set for the duration of the request, and you can expand on this by adding functions like `reset_card()`, `validate_card()`, `update_card()` and so on. If you need to store many cards, just use an array for the `$card` property and set/get the items by array index.

However, if you need the data to persist accross different requests, and the data is not static (for instance, it is updated after each request), you will have to use [session data](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) or store it in the database in order to retrieve it in the next request/page. Just store as little data as possible, like the card id perhaps.

Codeigniter (and PHP for that matter) provide several ways for you to approach a problem. In the end - use whatever method works best for you. Global variables can be a nice convenient lazy way to get/set arbitrary data, but if you can avoid using them - you should.

Comment: @Louis: Since Codeigniter runs as one big super-object, you can access it from anywhere as long as the class is loaded, and config items are always available. Not sure what you mean here, I get the feeling you're just being a child about my downvote.

Comment: Your answer simply doesn't cover what was asked in the question.

Comment: "`My question is, what is the best way to make the tiles' id and text available through multiple function calls without having to check and assign the array in each function?`" Setting a config item for example, will do exactly that. The difference is that you read from `CI_Config` rather than `$GLOBALS` or even worse: `global` variables.

Comment: `"How can I make Codeigniter function variables globally available?"` Setting a config item will not achieve global availability without the use of a global helper call to `get_instance();` or `config_item();` Why you think making a call to a global framework function is better practice than making a call to a global language array doesn't make any sense. They are both inherently dirty hacks using the global scope that should be avoided where possible.

Comment: If you've ever worked with or worked on third party code, you would understand. Using `CI_Config` as a storage object limits the scope, where `$GLOBALS` can be overridden *unintentionally* by someone else's usage of it in another part of the code, leading to very hard to trace errors. This is just one small example, it's a sign of bad design - when we have better solutions at our fingertips, they should be used.

Comment: This one seems to make more sense. I have no problem calling a library of sorts, but the data is static. The cards have been generated randomly, but there are only 10 cards at this stage. I am just trying to wrap my head around the way codeigniter handles these types of features. Thanks for the great ideas, both of you.

Comment: With static data, config files are a good way to go. Since the config item fetching functions in CI are designed a certain way, you might need to do something like `$var = config_item('card'); $card = $var[3];` to access a particular array index. In any case, you can certainly write your own "wrapper" function for it that references the config array.